# Python : Unable to locate element while scraping in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to scrape the phone number from a page. One such page is [this](https://www.europages.co.uk/PORT-INTERNATIONAL-GMBH/00000004710372-508993001.html). All the pages contain a link button with text `SEE PHONE NUMBER`, clicking on which reveals the phone number. I'm trying to scrape that particular phone number. Here is what I've tried so far :

```
company_url = 'https://www.europages.co.uk/PORT-INTERNATIONAL-GMBH/00000004710372-508993001.html'
d = {}
try :
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.get(company_url)
    link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('See phone number')
    link.click()
    driver.close()
    page = driver.page_source
    soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
    tel_no = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'info-tel-num'})
    tel_no = tel_no.text
    d['telephone'] = tel_no
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Error encountered : {e}')
```

But every time, it prints this error in the exception block :

> Error encountered :  Message: Unable to locate element: See phone number

This link button doesn't have any particular id or class, so I can't use `find_element_by_id` or `find_element_by_class`. Here is what I found by inspect element on that button (before clicking):

[image: inspect element result]

And here is the inspect element result after clicking the button :

[image: after clicking]
How to scrape this phone number? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try add some wait?

Comment: How will it help after `link.click()` if the failure is in the line before? it's probably page loading timing issue, you need to wait before trying to locate the element.

Answer (score 3):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to locate and `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick^='EpGetInfoTel']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'EpGetInfoTel') and text()='See phone number']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- To scrape the phone number you can use the following line of code:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'EpGetInfoTel') and text()='See phone number']//following::div[1]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  +49 04 03 01 00 00
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: phone]

Comment: first and most accurate answer! this one should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to click on see phone number

```
$("[itemprop='telephone'] a")[0].click();
```

and to get phone number value use this:

```
$("[itemprop='telephone'] [style='display: block;']")[0].innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebDriverWait` and click on the element with following xpath.Then get the `page_source` if you want to use BeautifulSoup as you are doing it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
company_url = 'https://www.europages.co.uk/PORT-INTERNATIONAL-GMBH/00000004710372-508993001.html'
d = {}
try :
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--incognito')
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.get(company_url)
    link =WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//a[contains(.,"See phone number")]')))
    link.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    page = driver.page_source
    driver.close()
    soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')
    tel_no = soup.find('div', {'class' : 'info-tel-num'})
    tel_no = tel_no.text
    d['telephone'] = tel_no
except Exception as e:
   print(f'Error encountered : {e}')


print(d)
```

Output on console:

```
{'telephone': '+49 04 03 01 00 00'}
```